@Autowired property not injected by Spring for unique value validator
I'm creating an application using Spring Boot, where I've got Employee entity with email field that has to be unique for each of the created entities.
Given entity:
package com.example.restcrudapi.models;

import com.example.restcrudapi.validators.ShouldStartWith;
import com.example.restcrudapi.validators.UniqueEmail;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name="employee")
@Getter
@Setter
public class  Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    @NotBlank(message = "First name is required")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(?!\\s).*(?<!\\s)$",
            message = "First name must not start or end with whitespace")
    @ShouldStartWith("Max")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^(?!\\s).*(?<!\\s)$",
            message = "First name must not start or end with whitespace")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[\\w-\\.]+@([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]{2,4}$",
            message="value must meet email format criteria")
    @NotBlank(message="email is required")
    @UniqueEmail
    private String email;

    @Min(0)
    @Max(100)
    @Column(name="number_of_points")
    private int points;

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String email, int points) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.points = points;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee {" +
                "id = " + id +
                ", first name = " + firstName + '\'' +
                ", last name = " + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email = " + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

UniqueEmail annotation code:
package com.example.restcrudapi.validators;

import jakarta.validation.Constraint;
import jakarta.validation.Payload;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueEmailValidator.class)
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UniqueEmail {
    public String message() default "employee with given email is already registered";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

UniqueEmailValidator
package com.example.restcrudapi.validators;

import com.example.restcrudapi.repositories.employee.EmployeeRepository;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class UniqueEmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueEmail, String> {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String email, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (email == null || email.isBlank()) {
            return true; // Let other annotations like @NotBlank handle null/empty cases
        }
        var isUniqueEmail = employeeRepository.existsByEmail(email);

        return isUniqueEmail;
    }
}

and EmployeeRepository
package com.example.restcrudapi.repositories.employee;

import com.example.restcrudapi.models.Employee;
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

import java.util.Optional;

@RepositoryRestResource
@Transactional
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
    boolean existsByEmail(String email);
}

With REST endpoints set up by spring-boot-starter-data-rest.
When calling POST /myapi/employees with an example request body:
{
    "firstName": "This One",
    "lastName": "Should not pass",
    "email": "pepefi11221@re.co",
    "points": 21
}

I can see that employeeRepository in UniqueEmailValidator is not injected despite using @Component and @Autowired annotations, and remains null, resulting in NullPointerException and HV000028: Unexpected exception during isValid call in the HTTP response.

I've tried using @Service instead @Component, also tinkered a bit with @Bean, to no avail - the result is always the same.
How to make Spring Boot inject employeeRepository correctly?

Have you enable JPA repositories by adding @EnableJpaRepositories to a config class (see this article from baeldung.com for details)? --- Do you have a [MRE], e.g. in form of a git repository?

Here is similar question.

@talexmovedtoCodidact the question you linked seems to be older. The official spring documentation (docs.spring.io) has an example simillar to what OP tries to achieve.

Yes. But the main idea stays. Hibernate doesn't know about spring, so you have to configure Hibernate with already initialized validator. I don't know how to do it though.

@Turing85 here's the repo with the code and SQL script to set up db. https://github.com/hubesal/03-rest-crud-api
I tried to add @EnableJpaRepositories as an annotation to RestCrudApiApplication class, but it didn't help out. Apologies for any stupid mistakes I potentially make, newbie to Java.

Can you show the full stack trace?

@hubesal 1. your sql-script to initialize the database is syntactically unsound - 2. No matter which endpoint I call, I get a 401 UNAUTHORIZED. I have no idea what you've configured; I already remove spring-boot-starter-security. Can you please fix the [MRE]? And providing a curl command to trigger the use case would also be helpful.

Okay, I was able to work around the security config issue and can now reproduce the error.

@AndreySmelik https://pastebin.com/zQXTzMRj here it is

If a ConstraintValidator instance is created by Spring, then the required dependencies are injected into it. The problem is that it is not only Spring that creates ConstraintValidator instances. Hibenate also creates ConstraintValidator instances when validating an object before writing it to the database. In this case, dependency injection does not occur.
However, you can configure Hibernate to use the ValidatorFactory provided by Spring. Then ConstraintValidator instances will be created in the Spring context with all dependencies injected. To do this, you need to tell Hibernate which factory to use using the jakarta.persistence.validation.factory property:
@Configuration
public class HibernateConfig implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

    @Autowired
    private ValidatorFactory validatorFactory;

    @Override
    public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.JAKARTA_VALIDATION_FACTORY, validatorFactory);
    }
}

In this case, you don't need to annotate the ConstraintValidator implementation as @Component. Spring and Hibernate will use LocalValidatorFactoryBean to obtain validators. Therefore, dependency injection will be performed.
For more information, see Spring Framework Reference.
Another cruder solution of the problem is to use a static field for dependency injection. In this case, you need to use @Component to tell Spring to create an instance of ConstraintValidator and inject dependencies into it when the application starts.
@Component
public class UniqueEmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueEmail, String> {

    private static final AtomicReference<EmployeeRepository> EMPLOYEE_REPOSITORY_HOLDER = new AtomicReference<>();

    @Autowired
    public void setEmployeeRepository(EmployeeRepository employeeRepository) {
        EMPLOYEE_REPOSITORY_HOLDER.set(employeeRepository);
    }

    // ...
}


For the 2nd solution, I see the employeeRepository is now resolved, but the validation still fails. Stack trace: https://pastebin.com/d5Xhqatm

@hubesal The problem is that at the time of validation Employee has not yet received an id. And since during validation you call employeeRepository.existsByEmail(), which is implemented as JPQL, Hibernate is forced to flush the persistence context, which leads to an error due to the absence of an id for Employee. The first thing that comes to mind to solve this problem is to use a new persistence context in the validation procedure. To do this, mark your postal address search service with the annotation @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW).

@hubesal If you use the second solution, do not mark the validator with the @Transactional annotation, since the validator in this case is not a spring bean and the annotation will not work. You need a separate transactional service.
